# How to format cash after 2 calculations Javascirpt

Tags: javascript, html

I use Javascript to calculate the product price. After selecting the  product to calculate the result of the first product I used tolocalString() to format the result was successful. However, when choosing the second product to enter the same data, the totalcash box is displayed NaN.

It seems that is history
after using toLocaleString() it can't be calculated
this is my code

```js
function sanpham1() {

  if (document.getElementById("ProductHGuard").checked) {
    var numberProduct = document.getElementById("numberProductHGuard").value;
    var priceproduct2 = document.getElementById("priceProductDIAsia").value;

    var result = numberProduct * 37500;
    var newresult = result.tolocalString();
    var tonggia = (priceproduct2 * 1.1) + (result * 1.1);
    var piceProduct1 = numberProduct * 25;
    var tonggiamoi = parseInt(tonggia);


    document.getElementById('priceProductHGuard').value = newresult.();
    document.getElementById('sumprice').value = tonggiamoi.toLocaleString();
    document.getElementById('numberProductHGuard1').value = piceProduct1;

  }
}

function sanpham2() {
  var numberProduct = document.getElementById("numberProductDIAsia").value;
  var priceproduct1 = document.getElementById("priceProductHGuard").value;

  if (document.getElementById("ProductDIAsia").checked) {
    var result = numberProduct * 23000;
    var tonggia = (priceproduct1 * 1.1) + (result * 1.1);
    var piceProduct2 = numberProduct * 20;
    var tonggiamoi = tonggia;

    document.getElementById('priceProductDIAsia').value = result.toLocaleString();
    document.getElementById('sumprice').value = tonggiamoi.toLocaleString();
    document.getElementById('numberProductDIAsia2').value = piceProduct2;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-borderless" style="border:1px solid gray;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="border:1px solid gray;" scope="col" colspan="2">Product</th>
      <th style="border:1px solid gray;" scope="col">Price</th>
      <th style="border:1px solid gray;" scope="col">Box</th>
      <th style="border:1px solid gray;" scope="col">Pice</th>
      <th style="border:1px solid gray;" scope="col"></th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" style="border:1px solid gray;"> <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="ProductHGuard" id="ProductHGuard"></th>
      <td style="border:1px solid gray;">product1</td>
      <td style="border:1px solid gray;">37,500円/箱</td>
      <td style="border:1px solid gray;"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="numberProductHGuard" id="numberProductHGuard" placeholder="2~" onchange="sanpham1()" disabled></td>
      <td style="border:1px solid gray;"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="numberProductHGuard1" id="numberProductHGuard1" disabled value="0"></td>
      <td style="border:1px solid gray;"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="priceProductHGuard" id="priceProductHGuard" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <script>
      $('#ProductHGuard').change(function() {


        if ($('#ProductHGuard').is(':checked') == true) {
          $('#numberProductHGuard').prop('disabled', false);
          $('#numberProductHGuard1').prop('disabled', false);


        } else {
          $('#numberProductHGuard').val('').prop('disabled', true);
          $('#numberProductHGuard1').prop('disabled', true);
          $('#numberProductHGuard1').val('');
          $('#priceProductHGuard').val('');
          $('#sumprice').val('');


        }

      });
    </script>
    <tr>
      <th style="border:1px solid gray;" scope="row"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="ProductDIAsia" id="ProductDIAsia" value=""></th>
      <td style="border:1px solid gray;">Product2</td>
      <td>23,000円/箱</td>
      <td style="border:1px solid gray;"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="numberProductDIAsia" id="numberProductDIAsia" placeholder="2~" onchange="sanpham2()" disabled></td>
      <td style="border:1px solid gray;"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="numberProductDIAsia2" id="numberProductDIAsia2" value="0" disabled></td>
      <td style="border:1px solid gray;"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="priceProductDIAsia" id="priceProductDIAsia" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <script>
      $('#ProductDIAsia').change(function() {


        if ($('#ProductDIAsia').is(':checked') == true) {
          $('#numberProductDIAsia').prop('disabled', false);
          $('#numberProductDIAsia2').prop('disabled', false);

        } else {
          $('#numberProductDIAsia').val('').prop('disabled', true);
          $('#numberProductDIAsia2').val('').prop('disabled', true);

          $('#priceProductDIAsia').val('');
          $('#sumprice').val('');


        }

      });
    </script>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" style="border:1px solid gray;">消費税</td>
      <td style="border:1px solid gray;">
        <p>10% <span style="font-weight:bold">自動計算結果の表示</span></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">合計</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sumprice" name="sumprice" pattern="^\$\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?$" value="" data-type="currency">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">円</span>
        </div>


      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There is errors in the code.What is `newresult .();` what is `resulttoLocaleString`

Comment: @epascarello sory copy mistake

Comment: There are script tags of jQuery splattered all over the HTML, two-thirds of the inputs are disabled. Format the code by  clicking the [TIDY] button.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] with the emphasis on **minimal**

Comment: Code still has `newresult .();` and you still have `result.tolocalString();`

Answer (score 0):

In your first function, you are not calling the intended method to get the string. Your code:

```
var newresult = result.tolocalString();
```

It should be:

```
var newresult = result.toLocaleString();
```

Comment: If so, the place to calculate the total amount will be sumresult=newresult1 = result.toLocaleString()+newresult2= result.toLocaleString();
results will be displayed NaN

Comment: @hiepHoangduc I don't quite follow.